vulkan APIをWindows10上でg++(minGW)コンパイラを使いライブラリリンクする方法が知りたい
質問内容
vulkan APIをWindows10上でg++(minGW)コンパイラを使いライブラリリンクしたいのですが、C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.290.0\Libパス内には.lib拡張子のファイルしか存在せずg++を用いた場合の.aファイルが存在しません。Visual Studioは使わないでビルドしたいのですが、その際はどうすればいいのでしょうか？
知りたいこと
vulkan APIをWindows10上でg++(minGW)コンパイラを使いライブラリリンクしたい
現状のエラーコード(最下部のコマンドを実行した際)
> g++ main.cpp -IC:\VulkanSDK\1.3.290.0\Include -LC:\VulkanSDK\1.3.290.0\Lib -lvulkan-1 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `vkCreateInstance@12'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices@12'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices@12'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties@12'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties@12'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x301): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR@20'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x433): undefined reference to `vkCreateDevice@16'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x45d): undefined reference to `vkGetDeviceQueue@16'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x487): undefined reference to `vkGetDeviceQueue@16'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4eb): undefined reference to `vkDestroyDevice@8'
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvodNRE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x501): undefined reference to `vkDestroyInstance@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

試したこと

ChatGPT, geminiなどの主要AIを利用して方法を模索しましたがどうやら、SDKをインストールするとLIBディレクトリ内に.aファイルが生成されるとの回答が両方のAIで生成されますが、そのようなファイルはありません
C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.290.0内で文字列検索(検索: [.a])をしましたがライブラリファイルがありません。

確認したこと
.libファイルがあるということは何かしらライブラリリンクを行う必要があるととを、上記のコンソールログも参考に考えました。
参考サイト
Vulkan SDK 公式サイト：
https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#windows
ビルド目的のウインドウ表示サンプルコード
#include <iostream>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wpragma-pack"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_vulkan.h>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows")
    #define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR
    #define PLATFORM_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME
#endif

#define APP_NAME "hello-triangle"
#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#ifndef UINT32_MAX
    #define UINT32_MAX 0xffffffff
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Vulkan_LoadLibrary(nullptr);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(APP_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 360, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN);

    uint32_t extensionCount;
    const char** extensionNames = 0;
    SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(window, &extensionCount, nullptr);
    extensionNames = new const char *[extensionCount];
    SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(window, &extensionCount, extensionNames);
    const VkInstanceCreateInfo instInfo = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO, // sType
        nullptr,                                // pNext
        0,                                      // flags
        nullptr,                                // pApplicationInfo
        0,                                      // enabledLayerCount
        nullptr,                                // ppEnabledLayerNames
        extensionCount,                         // enabledExtensionCount
        extensionNames,                         // ppEnabledExtensionNames
    };
    VkInstance vkInst;
    vkCreateInstance(&instInfo, nullptr, &vkInst);

    uint32_t physicalDeviceCount;
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(vkInst, &physicalDeviceCount, nullptr);
    std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> physicalDevices(physicalDeviceCount);
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(vkInst, &physicalDeviceCount, physicalDevices.data());
    VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice = physicalDevices[0];

    uint32_t queueFamilyCount;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(physicalDevice, &queueFamilyCount, nullptr);
    std::vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties> queueFamilies(queueFamilyCount);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(physicalDevice, &queueFamilyCount, queueFamilies.data());

    VkSurfaceKHR surface;
    SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface(window, vkInst, &surface);

    uint32_t graphicsQueueIndex = UINT32_MAX;
    uint32_t presentQueueIndex = UINT32_MAX;
    VkBool32 support;
    uint32_t i = 0;
    for (VkQueueFamilyProperties queueFamily : queueFamilies) {
        if (graphicsQueueIndex == UINT32_MAX && queueFamily.queueCount > 0 && queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT)
            graphicsQueueIndex = i;
        if (presentQueueIndex == UINT32_MAX) {
            vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(physicalDevice, i, surface, &support);
            if(support)
                presentQueueIndex = i;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    float queuePriority = 1.0f;
    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queueInfo = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO, // sType
        nullptr,                                    // pNext
        0,                                          // flags
        graphicsQueueIndex,                         // graphicsQueueIndex
        1,                                          // queueCount
        &queuePriority,                             // pQueuePriorities
    };
    
    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures deviceFeatures = {};
    const char* deviceExtensionNames[] = {VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME};
    VkDeviceCreateInfo createInfo = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO,   // sType
        nullptr,                                // pNext
        0,                                      // flags
        1,                                      // queueCreateInfoCount
        &queueInfo,                             // pQueueCreateInfos
        0,                                      // enabledLayerCount
        nullptr,                                // ppEnabledLayerNames
        1,                                      // enabledExtensionCount
        deviceExtensionNames,                   // ppEnabledExtensionNames
        &deviceFeatures,                        // pEnabledFeatures
    };
    VkDevice device;
    vkCreateDevice(physicalDevice, &createInfo, nullptr, &device);

    VkQueue graphicsQueue;
    vkGetDeviceQueue(device, graphicsQueueIndex, 0, &graphicsQueue);

    VkQueue presentQueue;
    vkGetDeviceQueue(device, presentQueueIndex, 0, &presentQueue);

    SDL_Log("Initialized with errors: %s", SDL_GetError());
    
    bool running = true;
    while(running) {
        SDL_Event windowEvent;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
            if(windowEvent.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
                break;
            }
    }

    vkDestroyDevice(device, nullptr);
    vkDestroyInstance(vkInst, nullptr);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Vulkan_UnloadLibrary();
    SDL_Quit();

    SDL_Log("Cleaned up with errors: %s", SDL_GetError());

    return 0;
}

コマンド
g++ main.cpp -IC:\VulkanSDK\1.3.290.0\Include -LC:\VulkanSDK\1.3.290.0\Lib -lvulkan-1 -lSDL2main -lSDL2


Wikipedia Mingw-w64に

32ビットまたは64ビットのx86実行ファイルを生成できる。ターゲット名はそれぞれi686-w64-mingw32とx86_64-w64-mingw32を使用する。

とあるようにi686-w64-mingw32は32bit実行ファイルを作成するので、 -LC:\VulkanSDK\1.3.290.0\Lib ではなく -LC:\VulkanSDK\1.3.290.0\Lib32 を参照してみてください。

undefined reference to `vkCreateInstance@12'


エラーメッセージに出てくる 関数名@サイズ という関数名の付け方も、32bit Windowsの __stdcall 呼び出し規則による関数名修飾によるものです。64bit呼び出し規則にはそのような関数名修飾はありません。


質問ですが\Lib32 というディレクトリが存在しないのですがその際はどうすればいいのでしょうか？

コンパイラを64bit版に切り替えるか、32bit版のSDKをインストールするか、ともかく環境を揃える必要があります。コンパイラについては質問文で何も触れられていませんし、Vulkanと無関係な話題になるのでそちらについては仕切り直してください。


ありがとうございます。質問ですが\Lib32 というディレクトリが存在しないのですがその際はどうすればいいのでしょうか？また、gccのコマンド等は同じでしょうか？
